# How to create a file with different extension using org.eclipse.ui.wizards.newresource.BasicNewFileResourceWizard

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is there a way to create a file with specific extension. Currently im creating a html kind file. Is there a way to give specific extension to the file while creating? Maybe .css or .js etc?

```xml
<extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
        <category id="com.ui.category" name="XXX Project">
        </category>

        <wizard
        category="com.ui.category"
        id="ui.wizard.NewFileWizard"
        name="Create a new File"
        icon="icons/new_project.png"
        class="org.eclipse.ui.wizards.newresource.BasicNewFileResourceWizard"
        project="true"
        >

        </wizard>
    </extension>
```

Comment: Note: You have `project="true"` on your wizard but you aren't creating a project - this is wrong.

Comment: May i also set created page content?For instance inside the css file i created can i add ready strings for every creation? @greg-449

Comment: You would have to override the WizardNewFileCreationPage to do that.

Comment: humm so can i handle extension and this one at once ? i kinda confused.. @greg-449

Comment: You can do it all at once but it requires a lot more work because more code has to be overridden. This is a new question.

Comment: I kinda tried to do it but having an error.. I will prepare the question. @greg-449

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create your own wizard to do this, extending `BasicNewFileResourceWizard`

The minimum code would be something like this:

```java
public class FileExtNewFileWizard extends BasicNewFileResourceWizard
{
  public FileExtNewFileWizard()
  {
    super();
  }


  @Override
  public void addPages()
  {
    super.addPages();

    // Get the page created by `super.addPages` and set the default file extension
    WizardNewFileCreationPage page = (WizardNewFileCreationPage)getPage("newFilePage1");

    page.setFileExtension("css");
  }
}
```